# How to specify a service in my docker-compose.yml file that has its own docker-compose.yml file in docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I am trying to set up a few services in my local docker environment. One of the services, as defined in my `docker-compose.yml` file, is as follows:

```
version: "3"

services:
  solr:
    image: solr:latest
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    container_name: solr
```

...which is pretty straightforward.

However, I also want to set up another service that has its own `docker-compose.yml` in it. If I simply specify a `FROM` in the Dockerfile for this service, it doesn't work as expected as the repo's `docker-compose.yml` includes services from other repositories as well.

What is the right way to configure such a service that has its own `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **extend** in yml file to call another docker-compose file. When defining any service in docker-compose.yml, you can declare that you are extending another service like this:

```
 web:
   extends:
     file: common-services.yml
     service: webapp
```

Ref : https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understand-the-extends-configuration

Note :  **extend** option is removed from  docker-compose version-3 and it is available only in version-2

Ref : https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services

Comment: what in the case of a remote repo? do i have to actually download the files into my local machine?

Comment: yes download and use it.. but am unable to find other way in docs